# How can I output month name in a given timezone

Tags: date, timezone

I would like to have the output of `date +"%B, %d %Y"` in my local timezone but considering another timezone for the names (month name in this case).

In my system the `date +"%B"` outputs (please note the missing 'y' on 'JanuarY') :

```
Januar
```

I tried:

`TZ=America/Los_Angeles date +"%B, %d %Y"`

Output:

```
Januar, 31 2016
```

From the man page:

```
%B     **locale's** full month name (e.g., January)
```

So, I tried to fetch another sequence than *%B* but, I cannot find one.

`TZ='America/Los_Angeles' date` give the expected output (I ran this command at ~20h in my local timezone)

```
So 31. Jan 11:01:30 PST 2016
```

Here are some information (if it's relevant):

```
$ date --version`
  date (GNU coreutils) 8.23

$ date +%Z
  CET

$ uname -a
  Linux host 4.2.0-25-generic #30-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jan 18 12:31:50 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: What is your desired output? How would the timezone change the month's name? If the date in the target timezone falls in a different month, then the corresponding month name will be shown. Please [edit] your question and show us what you would like `date` to print.

Comment: I'd like to have this output: `January, 31 2016` (timezone orthograph dependent, english in this case, with a 'y')

Comment: OK, please *[edit]* and add that information as well as what a simple `date` shows on your system. I'm still not sure if what you want is a different timezone or just the output in a different language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Month names are not tied to a timezone, but to **locale**.

```
$ LC_ALL=cs_CZ.utf8 date +%B
leden
$ LC_ALL=es_ES.utf8 date +%B
enero
```

Comment: so, you're simply telling me it's not possible to have this output with `date`

Can I change an environement variable to obtain a timezone-dependent output ?

Comment: @J.P.Quenord-Zermingore: No, I'm telling you the output depends on a variable. There are timezones that use more than one language.